# Send OpenCV image in POST response

Tags: python, django, opencv

I wish to send image through POST response after perform some processing on image.

```
cv2.putText(img,text, (x,y-15), font, 1,(255,0,0),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
```

I got data in `img`. How do I encapsulate the image in the post request? I tried with

```
return HttpResponse(img, content_type='image/jpg')
```

It shows nothing in Postman.

Comment: Maybe image is not `jpg`. Did you try `jpeg` instead? `HttpResponse(img, content_type="image/jpeg")`

Comment: try using `cv::imencode` to convert to jpg bytedata

Comment: @Micka yep, solved with that way =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the http.client to send the data below is a function which will send opencv frames to a flask server in a POST request

```
import http.client as httplib
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection('127.0.0.1', timeout=5)
def sendtoserver(frame):
    imencoded = cv2.imencode(".jpg", frame)[1]
    headers = {"Content-type": "text/plain"}
    try:
        conn.request("POST", "/", imencoded.tostring(), headers)
        response = conn.getresponse()
    except conn.timeout as e:
        print("timeout")


    return response
```

If you are using Flask you can use the following code to receive the frame at the server side

```
def process():
    frame = request.data
    image = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(frame, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    return Response('0', mimeType="multipart/x-mixed-replace")
```